# Desktop Icons Moving when copying new files to desktop in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

When I copy new files to Desktop in Windows 10 build 19041, other icons are moving. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on an empty space of your desktop, and check the View sub-menu.
If you see that the "Auto-arrange icons" option is checked, uncheck it and see
if that makes a difference. You should now be able to move the icons to their
appropriate positions on the desktop and Windows should not get in the way.

If the "Auto-arrange icons" option is already unchecked and icons are still moving,
the only solution is to use a third-party product to remember and restore
the layout of the desktop. Then all you have to do to move the new icons
to their place and use this product to keep the new layout.

Below are some free products for keeping desktop icons layouts:

- [ReIcon](https://www.sordum.org/8366/reicon-v1-9-restore-desktop-icon-layouts/)
- [Iconoid](https://www.sillysot.com/)
- [Icon Shepherd](https://www.winability.com/icon-shepherd/)

Comment: Auto-arrange icons option is already unchecked. it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second harry's guess about the source of the problem, but I would recommend [DesktopOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK) in case you can't find a "real" solution.

With DesktopOK you can set it to save the icon position in regular intervals this way you don't have to manually save the layout copy icons to your desktop.

Note: I'm not affiliated with DesktopOK

Answer (score 0):

have you ever download some system update packages before? Uninstall the previous update package might make it more stable.

Please try to right click the desktop, click View, clear the check before "Auto arrange icons".